# Getting exception while Creation a text file in Appdata folder, its saying File it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, file, text-files, streamwriter, userappdatapath

I am writing a text file in Appdata folder, I am creating a folder and creating a text file and in next line I am writing text into the file through StreamWriter. But here I am getting following exception.

**The process cannot access the file 'C:\sdfdfg\sdfsd\AppData\Roaming\MyFolder\myFile.txt' because it is being used by another process.**

This exception I am getting when I create file, if I run app second time than the app is writing the text into same file.

My Code is following

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
     File.Create(filePath);
     sb.AppendLine(line);
     using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
     {
         writer.Write(sb.ToString());
         writer.Close();
     }
}
```

I tried another function of File, File.WriteAllText(filePath, textToWrite); but it is also performing same way as above StreamWriter is behaving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to just leave out `File.Create()`.

[The constructor you're using for your StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx) will already create the file if it doesn't exist.

Another option is to pass the `FileStream` that `File.Create()` returns into an appropriate constructor of `StreamWriter`.

Comment: Thank you now i have removed the File.Create(filePath); StreamWriter will write the file., such a silly mistake i did.... :(, anyway thank you Willem van Rumpt.

cheers!